# How to replace the next record after a pattern matching using awk

Tags: gawk

How to replace(or modify) the next record after a pattern matching?
Ex:

```
1
2
3 blah
4 replace this record
5 blah
6 replace this record
7 
8
9
```

Here I want to skip or replace the fourth record and 6th record when the previous one record is "blah"

Answer (score 3):

This replaces the line after `blah`:

```
$ awk 'f{$0="replacement"; f=0} /blah/{f=1} 1' file
1
2
3 blah
replacement
5 blah
replacement
7 
8
9
```

#### How it works

- `f{$0="replacement"; f=0}`

  If `f` is true (nonzero), then replace the line and reset `f` to zero.
- `/blah/{f=1}`

  If this line matches the regex `blah`, then set `f` to true.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-whole-line.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` rather than `awk`:

```
sed -e '/blah/{ n; c\' -e 'replacement' -e '}' file
```

This looks for the lines matching the pattern `blah`.  When such a line is found, it is printed with `n`, which also immediately reads the next line of input. That next line is then changed with `c` to the replacement text.  Thie replacement text is printed at the end of the cycle.

Annotated `sed` script:

```sed
/blah/ {    ;# this is a "blah" line
    n       ;# output line and read next line
             # change the line just read
    c\
replacement
}
             # (implicitly print all lines)
```

This `sed` script would also work with `sed` in both OpenBSD and NetBSD even though the one-liner at the top does not work with these implementations due to something that they do wrong with the `c` command, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/blah/ {print $0 "\n" "replacement"; getline; next} 1' file
```

If the current line matches `blah` then print it, print `replacement` on a new line, get the next line of output (which we already replaced with "replacement") and **do nothing with it**, and then skip the remaining rule. The "remaining rule" (which is only applied to lines that don't match `blah` and don't **follow** a line matching blah) is to simply print the line.